# Is it OK to have more than 1 index.html on your website?

Tags: html, sitemap, directory

I have a **index.html** on my root folder of a subdomain

i.e. **example.example.com/index.html**

and then I made a second folder (which is located in the root folder)

**example.example.com/folder/index.html**

Is this good/recommended?

PS I'm pretty new to this so I have a follow up question. Does this have tie in to sitemaps in a big way and do people usually use an app to do the their "sitemapping" for them?

Comment: It's good , as long as you don't confuse with it. Xb

Comment: it's ok to have 2 index.html

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years OK, hehe :) How would it effect sitemapping and seo? Would it be better to have descriptive names instead of index?

Comment: You should always have an index, for instance when you go to google.com, you are actually getting google.com/index. If that page was named 'home' people would need to type google.com/home to get something to load. For all other pages descriptive names will be fine, but you always need a default document to be served.

Comment: @GriffinM nope. That is set by .htaccess you may have it name home.html but display it as www.example.com/index

Comment: @GriffinM OK but how about having a **index.html** in a sub folder like **example.example.com/folder/index.html** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's fine, but there should only be 1 per folder. The index.html is the file your webserver will serve up if another is not specified, so it is normal to have one in each directory.

As far as creating the sitemap, there are a lot of tools online that will create an XML sitemap for you and that is what people usually use.

Comment: This can be a choice for module based hosting. If you have an application which were build by various UI Teams you can host each and every module as a separate application folder, each will have index.htm page as a default page. It would be right use case for microservice.

Answer (score 2):

Its ok to have multiple index.html files, may be some experts will say its not a recommended way. But in my point of view as long as you know that what's going on you can have tons of index.html .