# Link in html page on android doesn't work

Tags: android, html

I made two html pages on a desktop computer and transferred them to a mobile phone and put them in the same folder. The operating system on the mobile phone is android 8.1.0. When I open one of the pages, it opens in google chrome but the link to the other page doesn't work.

This is code for first page:

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>index1</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>

        <a href="index2.html">go to index2</a>
            
    </body>
            
</html>
```

This is code for second page:

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>index2</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>

        <a href="index1.html">go to index1</a>
            
    </body>
            
</html>
```

Works perfectly on a desktop computer but does not work on a mobile phone.

Comment: is path problem i think, because chrome try to go to your first path /index2.html. for example if you put in the folder /test/index.html, you must insert all path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it OK to have more than 1 index.html on your website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312717/is-it-ok-to-have-more-than-1-index-html-on-your-website)

Comment: You can have only 1 `index.html` file per folder. That might be your issue here.

Comment: @Simone Rossaini I tried to look through google chrome browser on my mobile which is the path for htmls I use and used those paths but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `When I open one of the pages, i` Please tell exactly how you do that. All depends on how you ask Chrome to open a html page.

Comment: @blackapps single touch on html

Comment: Where do you see an html? What are you doing? Please be exact! I still know nothing.

Comment: @blackapps Make two html files on your computer, use the code I left above (or make what you think is necessary to write a link and so on), test on your computer if it does linking from one page to the other page, IF IT DOES, copy those two html file to your mobile in a folder you want and test on your mobile to see if the linking from one page to the other works. I don't know how you run html files on your mobile, I just touch the html file and it opens in the google chrome browser.

Comment: You did not have to sum up what i have to do as i knew that before of course. You only had to tell which app you used to see -html- files on your device. You did not tell that. How can i help you if you dont tell what you do. If you reboot your device then do you see those files? No. So what do you do and/or which app do you use to see and open those files?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. In my phone, if you want links to work, than links to files do not end with the file name and extension but with the file number. I could read the file number when I opened that file with the google chrome app in the address/search bar. And I had to install some text editor and work directly on mobile. This is what the code for linking two html pages looked like in the end:

First page:

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>index1</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>

        <a href="content://0@media/external/file/7912">go to index2</a>
            
    </body>
            
</html>
```

Second page:

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>index2</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>

        <a href="content://0@media/external/file/7911">go to index1</a>
            
    </body>
            
</html>
```

Thanks a lot guys for the help, I appreciate every effort.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this problem by just replace the URL in the browser with the form :
file:///storage/emulated/0/folder1/folder2.../file.extention

Answer (score 0):

Try to put / before your the file name

```
 <a href="/index1.html">go to index1</a>
```